# location path search with param not navigate to next page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to pass a parameter to the next page (edit page) by clicking edit button. I tried the following code but it's not working. The URL just shown like below quote but the page shows blank and the controller is not loaded also. What is wrong here?

```
http://localhost:8080/#/group/edit?id=586351373b6bba91152ab744
```

**View**

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="doEdit(item._id)" title="Edit">Edit</md-button>
```

**Route**

```
$routeProvider.when('/group/edit', {
      templateUrl: 'template/group_edit.html',
      controller: 'GroupEditCtrl'
})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.doEdit = function (id) {
    $location.path('/group/edit').search({id: id});
}
```

Comment: but are you using route params in any way - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams ? - e.g. in your `GroupEditCtrl` you could inject $routeParams to get the id and save it on the scope / controller model.

Comment: I don't want to use routeParams anyway because later i need to pass more than 1 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some more code could be useful to understand what's going wrong, this simple snippet seems to do the job.

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

angular
  .module('BlankApp')
  .config(['$routeProvider', setupRoutes])
  .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$location', ListController])
  .controller('GroupEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',GroupEditCtrl]);

function setupRoutes($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
        when("/", { controller: "ListController", templateUrl: "list.html" });
  $routeProvider.when('/group/edit', {
      templateUrl: 'edit.html',
      controller: 'GroupEditCtrl'
  })
}

function ListController($scope, $location) {
  $scope.item = {_id: 123}
  $scope.doEdit = function (id) {
    $location.path('/group/edit').search({id: id});
  }
}

function GroupEditCtrl($scope, $location) {
  $scope.locationParam = $location.search().id
  $scope.goBack = function() {
    $location.path('/');
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
  
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  
  <ng-view></ng-view>
 
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="doEdit(item._id)" title="Edit">Edit</md-button>
</script>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit.html">
    ehy edit! id: <pre>{{locationParam | json}}</pre> <br/>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="goBack()" title="Back">Back</md-button>
</script>
  
  
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
</body>
</html>
```